# How do I disconnect remote-exec in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have this issue in my google cloud platform wherein a default global user "gcp-root" conflicts with our ansible list of users.
So as workaround, I'm doing the following:

```
sudo adduser -u 9999 -G google-sudoers tmproot
sudo cp -Rfvp /home/gcp-root/.ssh /home/tmproot/
sudo chown tmproot:tmproot -Rf /home/tmproot/
```

Here's my terraform remote-exec block(s):

```
  ## Create a 'tmproot' as default full sudoer in gcp (gcp-root) has a uid
  ## that conflicts with one of ansible list of users.
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo adduser -u 9999 -G google-sudoers tmproot",
      "sudo cp -Rfvp /home/gcp-root/.ssh /home/tmproot/",
      "sudo chown tmproot:tmproot -Rf /home/tmproot/",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "gcp-root"
      private_key = "${file("${var.ssh_key_location}")}"
      host        = "${google_compute_address.static-ip-address.address}"
    }
  }

  ## Delete gcp-root
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo userdel gcp-root",
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "tmproot"
      private_key = "${file("${var.ssh_key_location}")}"
      host        = "${google_compute_address.static-ip-address.address}"
    }
  }
```

When I applied the terraform code, it results into the following:

```
null_resource.ansible_provisioning: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Host: <REDACTED>
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   User: gcp-root
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): Connected!
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): ‘/home/gcp-root/.ssh’ -> ‘/home/tmproot/.ssh’
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): ‘/home/gcp-root/.ssh/authorized_keys’ -> ‘/home/tmproot/.ssh/authorized_keys’
null_resource.ansible_provisioning: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Host: <REDACTED>
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   User: tmproot
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Password: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Private key: true
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): Connected!
null_resource.ansible_provisioning (remote-exec): userdel: user gcp-root is currently used by process 1359


Error: error executing "/tmp/terraform_633887752.sh": Process exited with status 8
```

So obviously, the issue is that the 1st remote-exec(using user 'gcp-root') is still connected, and hence, the 2nd remote-exec(using user 'tmproot') can't delete 'gcp-root'.

If only I can disconnect the 1st remote-exec, that would seem to solve my problem but it seems I don't have that option in terraform's docs. Searching google doesn't seem to return any hints.

Is there a better way for me to accomplish my objective?

Any hints/sugesstions surely welcome and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a viable solution to my problem by adding a startup script metadata in google cloud platform.

In metadata, I added the key:

```
startup-script
```

With the value:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo usermod -u 9999 gcp-root
sudo groupmod -g 9999 gcp-root
sudo chown gcp-root.gcp-root -Rf /home/gcp-root
```

For reference, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

And issue solved.